# Acentos desconfigurando ao passar dados de um txt para uma lista em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um script python que pega palavras de um arquivo ".txt" por meio do método open e as coloca em uma lista. Porém, se a palavra no arquivo de texto possui algum acento, quanto passada para a lista em python o acento vira "Äe" por exemplo. Gostaria de saber como posso impedir que esse problema aconteça.

Arquivo txt

`Até!
Tchau!
Nunca é um adeus!
Fui!`

Trecho python

`chats = open('dialogo/'+ arquivos, 'r').readlines()`

Quando dou `print()` na lista chat, **os caracteres com acento vem desconfigurados do arquivo txt**.

Comment: O Python, por padrão, abre o arquivo com a codificação UTF-8. O arquivo foi criado com esta codificação?

Comment: Sim, a codificação já está em UTF-8...